# How to solve Runtime Error: Empty min/max for tensor Cast while doing post-training quantization (fully quantized tflite model from saved_model)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, google-coral, edge-tpu

I try to create fully quantized tflite model to be able to run it on coral. I downloaded SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 640x640 from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md

I installed in virtual environment tf-nightly-2.5.0.dev20201123 tf-nightly-models and tensorflow/object_detection_0.1

I run this code to do post training quantization

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import numpy as np
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('./0-ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/saved_model/',signature_keys=['serving_default']) # path to the SavedModel directory

VIDEO_PATH = '/home/andrej/Videos/outvideo3.h264'
def rep_data_gen():
    REP_DATA_SIZE = 10#00
    a = []
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_PATH)
    i=0
    while(video.isOpened()): 
        ret, img = video.read()
        i=i+1
        if not ret or i > REP_DATA_SIZE:
          print('Reached the end of the video!')
          break
        img = cv2.resize(img, (640, 640))#todo parametrize based on network size
        img = img.astype(np.uint8)
        #img = (img /127.5) -1 #
        #img = img.astype(np.float32)#causing types mismatch error
        a.append(img)
    a = np.array(a)
    print(a.shape) # a is np array of 160 3D images
    for i in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a).batch(1).take(REP_DATA_SIZE):
        yield [i]

#tf2 models
converter.allow_custom_ops=True
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = rep_data_gen
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
#converter.quantized_input_stats = {'inputs': (0, 255)} #does not help
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8  # or tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8  # or tf.uint8
quantized_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('quantized_model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(quantized_model)
```

I got

```
RuntimeError: Max and min for dynamic tensors should be recorded during calibration: Failed for tensor Cast
Empty min/max for tensor Cast
```

Comment: Are you able to share FP lite model?

Comment: http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz

Comment: Unfortunately there is no tflite model inside archive.

Comment: yes, I am trying to get tflite model from saved_model (.pb extension)

Comment: May you please convert model to tflite without quantization and share it so we can look what ops cause problem? Also comment `converter.allow_custom_ops=True` I am not sure you have implemented custom ops in your runtime.

Comment: You will need a quantized TFlite model first.  Run that on a CPU or GPU and adjust your model until you are happy with the results.   Then you can use the edgetpu_compiler to create an image to run on the edge TPU:  https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/compiler/    You might want to start with a known-good edge TPU model here: https://coral.ai/models/  test it on the edge TPU, and then modify it, quantize, and see how it differs.  640x640 seems large.  Published models are up to 300x300.

Answer (score 2):

I trained the same model,  `SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 640x640`, using the script `model_main_tf2.py` and then exported the checkpoint to `saved_model` using the script `exporter_main_v2.py`. When trying to convert to ".tflite" for use on Edge TPU I was having the same problem.

The solution for me was to export the trained model using the script `export_tflite_graph_tf2.py` instead of `exporter_main_v2.py` to generate the `saved_model.pb`. Then the conversion occurred well.

Maybe try to generate a saved_model using `export_tflite_graph_tf2.py`.